# No audio from AVCaptureSession after changing AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I'm making an app that supports both video playback and recording. I always want to allow background audio mixing except for during video playback (during playback, background audio should be muted). Therefore, I use the two methods below while changing the state of playback. When my AVPlayer starts loading, I call `MuteBackgroundAudio`, and when I dismiss the view controller containing it, I call `ResumeBackgroundAudio`. This works as expected, and the audio returns successfully after leaving playback.

The issue is that after doing this at least once, whenever I record anything using `AVCaptureSession`, no sounds gets recorded. My session is configured like so:

```
AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] firstObject];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error];

if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

if ([self.session canAddInput:audioDeviceInput])
{
    [self.session addInput:audioDeviceInput];
}

[self.session setAutomaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession:NO];

// ... videoDeviceInput
```

Note that I have not set `usesApplicationAudioSession`, so it defaults to `YES`.

```
void MuteBackgroundAudio(void)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        if ([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying] && !isMuted)
        {
            isMuted = YES;

            NSError *error = nil;
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                             withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker
                                                   error:&error];
            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"DEBUG - Set category error %ld, %@", (long)error.code, error.localizedDescription);
            }

            NSError *error2 = nil;
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES
                                           withOptions:0
                                                 error:&error2];
            if (error2)
            {
                NSLog(@"DEBUG - Set active error 2 %ld, %@", (long)error.code, error.localizedDescription);
            }
        }
    });
}

void ResumeBackgroundAudio(void)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        if (isMuted)
        {
            AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

            NSError *deactivationError = nil;
            [audioSession setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&deactivationError];

            if (deactivationError)
            {
                NSLog(@"DEBUG - Failed at deactivating audio session, retrying...");
                ResumeBackgroundAudio();
                return;
            }

            isMuted = NO;
            NSLog(@"DEBUG - Audio session deactivated");

            NSError *categoryError = nil;
            [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                          withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                error:&categoryError];

            if (categoryError)
            {
                NSLog(@"DEBUG - Failed at setting category");
                return;
            }

            NSLog(@"DEBUG - Audio session category set to mix with others");

            NSError *activationError = nil;
            [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];

            if (activationError)
            {
                NSLog(@"DEBUG - Failed at activating audio session");
                return;
            }

            NSLog(@"DEBUG - Audio session activated");
        }
    });
}
```

**Debugging**

I have noticed that the audioSession always needs two tries to successfully deactivate after calling `ResumeBackgroundAudio`. It seems my AVPlayer does not get deallocated or stopped in time, due to this comment in `AVAudioSession.h`:

> Note that this method will throw an exception in apps linked on or
>   after iOS 8 if the session is set inactive while it has running or
>   paused I/O (e.g. audio queues, players, recorders, converters, remote
>   I/Os, etc.).

The fact that no sound gets recorded bring me to believe the `audioSession` does not actually get activated, but my logging says it does (always in the second iteration of the recursion).

I got the idea of using recursion to solve this problem from [this post](http://iknowsomething.com/ios-sdk-spritekit-sound/).

To clarify, the flow that causes the problem is the following:

1. Open app with Spotify playing
2. Begin playback of any content in the app
3. Spotify gets muted, playback begins (`MuteBackgroundAudio`)
4. Playback ends, Spotify starts playing again (`ResumeBackgroundAudio`)
5. Start recording
6. Stop recording, get mad that there is no audio

Comment: I am having this exact issue. Only my audio never works the first time regardless of the circumstance and I need to remove and re-add the audio input/output to get anything.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the exact same issue as you're describing, down to the very last detail (`[audioSession setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&deactivationError];` failed the first time no matter what)

The only acceptable way, for my case, was to stop then start the AVCaptureSession. I'm not entirely sure but I think this is the same exact way Whatsapp handles it - their camera behaves exactly like mine with the solution I'm suggesting.

Removing and adding the same audio input on the already running session also seemed to work but I got a terrible camera freeze - nothing compared to the session start / stop.

The recursion solution is nice, but I think it would be a great idea to 'throttle' that recursion call (add a short delay & a max retry count of some sort) in case for a legit reason the set fails every time. Otherwise your stack will overflow and your app will crash.

If you or anyone found a better solution to this I would love to know it.